# How to expire the activation link in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php script that sends an activation link via email to the users so they can activate their account. The link is like this: `mysite.com/activation.phpid?id=20`

How can I create the link to expire after 24 hours?

I haven't tried anything as I couldn't find anything to teach me how to do it. all I know is that I might be able to do this by storing something in mysql but how?

it will be great if someone could tell me the step by step instruction please.

Thanks

Comment: Store a timestamp from when the activation email was sent. Then when they go to the URL, just check if the ID is expired or not.

Answer (score 4):

Make the link like this:

```
$time = time();
$hash = md5($id . $time . "somerandomsalt"); // check this again in activation.php
$link = "activation.php?id=" . $id . "&hash=" . $hash . "&time=" . $time;
```

Then in `activation.php` you check if the hash matches. Oh, and check the time of course :P

You could obfuscate it a bit to hide the *id*, *hash* and *time* query parameters, but this is the basics.

Comment: Thanks, do I need to put this code in my activation.php file?           also, how can I check if the hash matches and the time? this is way out of my league!!!

Comment: The hash is generated by `md5($id . $time . "somerandomsalt");`. So in `activation.php` you get the _id_ and _time_ from `$_GET` and do the same `md5(...)`. Check if the output matches the _hash_ in `$_GET`. As for `time`: check that: `$_GET["time"] > time() - 24 * 60 * 60`.

Comment: i am so confused! any way i can post my activation.php code here ? its 200 characters too long!! i just need you to view my code if possible as I did try your suggestion and didn't work!!

Comment: here is the first part of the activation.php code:                      '<?  
include_once "scripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$id = ereg_replace("[^0-9]", "", $id);
if (!$id) {
 echo "Missing Data to Run";
 exit(); 
}
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE members SET emailactivated='1' WHERE id='$id'"); 
$sql_doublecheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE id='$id' AND emailactivated='1'"); 
$doublecheck = mysql_num_rows($sql_doublecheck);'

Comment: and here is the rest of it:                                                           if($doublecheck == 0){ 
print "<br /><br /><div align=\"center\"><h3><strong><font color=red>Your account could not be activated!</font></strong><h3><br /></div>"; 
} elseif ($doublecheck > 0) {
print "<br /><br /><h3><font color=\"#0066CC\"><strong>Your account has been activated!<br /><br />
</strong></font><a href=\"login.php\">Click Here</a> to log in now.</h3>"; 
}

Comment: Hey Mr.Halcyon, Can you help me with example of somerandomsalt?

Comment: Hey Mr.Rooz far, Have you found any solution? Please share with me.

Answer (score 1):

Just add an extra field in your database with the expiration date of the link. When the link is clicked you can then check the date to make sure it isn't expired.

**edit**

I'm guessing at your column and table names.

```
SELECT IF (DATEDIFF(date_registered, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) <= 0, 1, 0) AS expired
FROM users
WHERE id = 20
```

If `expired` is 1 then the link is expired. If it is `0` then it is valid.

Comment: how can i check the date stored in the mysql field? my script already stores the date that users registered on. so doing it your way is could easier and more appropriate. any script sample or tutorials that I can follow?

Comment: Thanks, The date is saved in the members table in signupdate column. do i need to put your code in my activation.php file? any chnace you could tell me the steps that i need follow please?